# Fontawsome PRO 6 Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I have been trying to add these fonts into my xamarin project , but I don't know what Iam doing wrong. All I get is a question ( ? )icon .
These are my steps

**Edits**

1. Added a new folder named fonts and copied the font inside my forms project
   See below

[image]

1. Assembly.cs on ios project

[image]

Also , again inside the resources just in case
[image]

Now, on xaml
[image]

Results
[image]

2. Download to the font awesome pro 6
3. [image: List item]
4. Add the fonts to my Xam Project ios and android
   [image]

[image]

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ExportFont attribute in your shared project.The most obvious place would be inside your App.xaml.cs or AssemblyInfo.cs. However, since the attribute will register this on assembly level, you can put this anywhere. The placement of the attribute depends on how visible you want to make it to other/future developers.

Anywhere outside a namespace will work. Just add this, you don’t need to include the subfolders:

```
 [assembly: ExportFont("Samantha.ttf")]
```

assemblyinfo.cs like this:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Samantha.ttf", Alias = "Samantha")]
[assembly: ExportFont("Pacifico.ttf", Alias = "Pacifico")]
[assembly: ExportFont("HugMe.ttf", Alias = "HugMe")]
```

Usage:

```
<Label FontFamily="Samantha" />
```

Note:
Add the font file (otf or ttf) to your shared project and mark it as embedded resource

[image: Like this]

Comment: if this is helpful please accept my question else ask me for more details

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please check my edits in the original post, Iam  still missing something ?

Comment: in you info.ps enable fonts

Comment: <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>OpenSans-Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>OpenSans-Regular.ttf</string>
</array>

Comment: open your info.ps in editing mode and add this code, check if it works. if not then open info.ps and search for fonts and enable them